# Unable to deploy model on endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, mlops

[EDITED] I want to deploy my model on an endpoint so i can start making predictions.

I followed these steps:

1. Create the model, create a docker image, push it into Artifact Registry
2. Upload the model to Vertex AI:

```
gcloud ai models upload --container-image-uri=<REGION>-docker.pkg.dev/<PROJECT>/<REPOS>/<MODEL>:latest --region=<REGION> --display-name=my-model
```

3. Create an endpoint on Vertex AI:

```
gcloud ai endpoints create --display-name=my-model-endpoint --region=<REGION>
```

4. Deploy the model to the endpoint:

```
gcloud ai endpoints deploy-model <ENDPOINT_ID> --model <MODEL_ID> -display-name my-model --traffic-split=0=100 --region <REGION> --machine-type=n1-standard-8 --enable-access-logging
```

Here's the message:

Model server terminated: model server container terminated: exit_code: 0 reason: "Completed" started_at { seconds: 1684309447 } finished_at { seconds: 1684309449 } . Model server logs can be found at xxxxx

[image: 14144.png]

When i check the logs:

[image: 85067.png]

As you can see i have no errors.

What i tried:

- upsized the machine-type
- deployed with a python script
- deployed manually using the portal
- changed my model to a simple linear regression to test

Comment: I tried with a simple linear regression, but it still doesn't work, i really don't know why, it doesn't seem to be related to the model, nor the endpoint.... i don't know

Answer (score 0):

An exit code 0 means a training job completes successfully. Also, it is probably because of your current [machine type](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/configure-compute#machine-types).

You might want to upsize it for more memory(GB) allocation.You can also review this issue in [Google Cloud Community](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/AI-ML/Vertex-AI-deploy-custom-model-error-Model-server-terminated/m-p/491627) for other references.

Comment: i tried to allocate more by changing from "n1-standard-2" to "n1-standard-8", still doesn't work. i'll edit my original post, it may help

Comment: Have you filed a case in buganizer regarding this?